# How to generate LaTeX documents with Perl

Tags: programming, automation, scripts

I have to generate Software Requirement Specification documents in LaTeX. I have to use Perl to accomplish this. The documents consist of tables, lists, pictures, TOC, table of figures, headings and so on ...

Can you give me some general advice on how to approach such a task? Are there maybe some Modules you found useful or "traps" I have to be aware off?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The `latex-project` tag is about the LaTeX develop project itself. A `latex` tag is superfluous on this site. There is no `ubuntu` tag on http://askubuntu.com either, or a `perl` tag on http://perlmonks.org. Ok, the latter doesn't have any tag system, but would be also an good alternative site to ask this question.

Comment: Thank you. The latex tags I used indeed make no sense.

Comment: Googling 'perl template latex' returned several starting points, mostly involving the [Template::Latex](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Latex) module from CPAN. A [PracTeX Journal article](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/hardwick/hardwick.pdf) is also available.

Comment: Where do need the most help? The LaTeX side, e.g. which LaTeX code to choice for this? Or the Perl side, e.g. organizing the script and loading of templates, etc? Because the second part would be off-topic here and would be better suited on http://stackoverflow.com or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, besides the already mentioned external non-SX site http://perlmonks.org.

Comment: That is the first time I use LaTeX, so I thought it would be a good idea to ask for some general advice or hints from people who are already generating LaTeX-docs with Perl. I have no specific problem, I just couldn't find a point to start. For example, thanks to the comments now I know, that it is a good idea to use templates. Now I know I must prepare/split my data in a way that it can be used to feed templates and I got two example programs to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you two examples of LaTeX-generating Perl script written by me. Both are on CTAN (not CPAN!) and called [`sty2dtx`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/sty2dtx) and [`texdef`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/texdef).

For the first I read and parse some LaTeX code from an existing package (`.sty` file) and generate a `.dtx` file (Documented LaTeX) from it by adding the appropriate documentation macros, so that the package author only has to fill in the descriptions. I decided to write my own little template engine which simply places `<+NAME+>` markers where I need to add material. The template itself is actually at the end of the script in the `__DATA__` section. Then I have a hash with of this variables, so I only need to loop over the template, find the markers, extract the `NAME` part and replace the whole marker with the `NAME` entry in the hash. Have a look at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. I think the scripts are a good starting point.

Comment: url doesn't work please